# Rewrite HasValue to the ?? Operators

Tags: c#, nullable

Is it safe to rewrite the following code:

```
bool b = foo.bar.HasValue ? foo.bar.Value : false;
```

to

```
bool b = foo.bar.Value ?? false;
```

where `bar` is the nullable type `bool?`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The easiest fix there is

```
bool b = foo.bar.GetValueOrDefault();
```

which is also actually cheaper than `.Value` as it omits the has-value check. It will default to `default(T)` , which is indeed `false` here (it just returns the value of the underlying `T` field, without any checks at all).

If you need a different default to `default(T)`, then:

```
var value = yourNullable.GetValueOrDefault(yourPreferredValue);
```

Comment: Learn something new every day. Don't know how long I've been using `Nullable<T>` and just not known about those methods.

Answer (score 18):

What you want is:

```
bool b = foo.bar ?? false;
```

This is (surprisingly) safe and an intended use for the null-coalescing operator.

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for a **nullable value types** as well as reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

In the case of `Nullable<T>`, it is functionally equivalent to [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d.aspx).

The code:

```
bool b = foo.bar.Value ?? false;
```

Will cause a compiler-error, because you cannot apply the operator to value types, and `Nullable<T>.Value` always returns a value-type (or throws an exception when there is no value).

Comment: +1 for spotting the "will not compile" - although I disagree about "surprisingly" - mainly because 99% of the time I find myself using it on value types :)

Comment: It's a surprise to many because the effective behaviour of null-coalesce changes depending on whether you're dealing with reference. For reference types, the IL is equivalent to `x == null ? x : false;`. For `Nullable<T>`, ?? is replaced with a call to `GetValueOrDefault(T);`. Surprise!

Comment: As useful as the reply currently marked as answer is, I feel this response is the actual answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

No - this is not safe.

The line:

```
bool b = foo.bar.Value ?? false;
```

will throw an InvalidOperationException if foo.bar has no value.

Instead use

```
var b = foo.bar ?? false;
```

---

**Update** - I just learned about `.GetValueOrDefault();` from the other answers - that looks like a very good suggestion to use!

---

**Update 2** - @ProgrammingHero's answer is also correct (+1 added!) - the line:

```
bool b = foo.bar.Value ?? false
```

actually won't compile - because of `Error  50  Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'`

Comment: 'foo.bar' is of type 'bool?', but 'foo.bar.Value' is just 'bool' which is the reason why you should apply the '??' operator to 'foo.bar' only - which has the correct type. Remember that '??' replaces null by the value you've specified which requires a nullable or a reference type, and  bool is just a value type.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

> The Value property returns a value if
>   one is assigned, otherwise a
>   System.InvalidOperationException is
>   thrown.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

So if hasValue is false then you will get an exception thrown in your second one when you try to run it.

Answer (score 2):

`ffoo.bar ?? false` would be more safer to use

Answer (score 2):

```
bar.Value ?? false
```

has compilation error, because left operand of ?? operator should be of reference or nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244582/1016343) article in Stackoverflow too - it is an elegant null checking in the style `obj.IfNotNull(lambdaExpression)` - returning the object you want if obj is not null otherwise just null (but without throwing an exception).

I used it with the Entity Framework if you're accessing a referenced entity, e.g.

```
var str=Entity1.Entity2.IfNotNull(x=>x.EntityDescription) ?? string.Empty
```

which returns `EntityDescription` contained in `Entity2` which is referenced by `Entity1` - or an empty string if any object `Entity1` or `Entity2` is `null`. Without [`IfNotNull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244582/1016343) you would get a long and ugly expression.

The extension method `IfNotNull` is defined there as follows:

```
public static TOut IfNotNull<TIn, TOut>(this TIn v, Func<TIn, TOut> f)
    where TIn : class 
    where TOut: class
{
    if (v == null) return null; else return f(v);
}
```

---

**Update:**
If you update the code to **C# version 6.0** (.NET Framework 4.6 - but [seems to support older frameworks 4.x too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28921701/1016343)), there is a new operator available which makes this task easy: The **"elvis" operator** **`?.`**.

It works as follows:

```
var str=(Entity1.Entity2?.EntityDescription) ?? string.Empty
```

In this case, if `Entity2` is `null`, evaluation stops and `(...)` becomes `null` - after which the `?? string.empty` part replaces `null` by `string.Empty`. In other words, it works the same way as `.IfNotNull(...)` would.

Answer (score 0):

foo.bar.Value represents the non-nullable value when there is one, **and throws an InvalidOperationException** if there’s no real value.